If $f$ have not saddle point on compact surface, how to show $f$ have only one maxima and on minima?
When I read a paper, the author seemly think it is right that "Let $f$ be smooth function on compact surface. If $f$ have not saddle point (degenerate critical point), then $f$ have only one maxima and one minima. "  But he don't give proof.
Geometrically, it seems he was right. If there are two maxima points,  connect the two points, seemly,  there must be  saddle point on the shortest connected line. But I can't give a hard proof, so ask.

What is the name of the paper?

@FabrizzioMuzz  It is Hamilton's The Ricci flow on surfaces.  I asked a lot of questions about this paper, and I hid it for fear of annoying everyone.

Denote the connected, compact surface (two-dimensional manifold) by $S$ and let the smooth function $f$ on $S$ have no saddle points or degenerate critical points.
If $S$ is orientable, the Euler characteristic $\chi(S)$ is equal to $2-2g$, where $g\geq 0$ is the genus ("number of holes") of the surface.
The well-known equation from Morse Theory (see "Morse inequalities" section of Morse theory Wikipedia article) gives
$$\chi(S)=\sum_{\gamma}(-1)^{\gamma}C_{\gamma}=C_0-C_1+C_2$$
where $C_{\gamma}$ is the number of critical points (of $f$) of index $\gamma$ (a local minimum has index $0$, a saddle point has index $1$, and a local maximum has index $2$). Because there are no saddle points ($C_1=0$), we have $2-2g=C_0+C_2$, and due to the Extreme Value Theorem ($f$ is a continuous function on a compact surface), there is at least one local minimum and one local maximum of $f$.
From this, we conclude that $g=0$ and $C_0=C_2=1$.
On the other hand, if $S$ is nonorientable, $\chi(S)=2-k$, where $k\geq 1$ is the genus ("number of cross-caps") of the surface, and so
$$2-k=C_0+C_2.$$
As there is again at least one local minimum and one local maximum, there is no $k$ satisfying this equation and so $S$ cannot be nonorientable.
In conclusion, if $S$ is a connected, compact surface with no saddle points or degenerate critical points, $S$ is orientable with genus $0$ and $f$ has exactly one local minimum and exactly one local maximum.
If $S$ is not connected (i.e. consists of multiple connected components) with no saddle points or degenerate critical points, it is not too difficult to show (using the fact that the Euler characteristic of $S$ is the sum of component Euler characteristics) that there is one local minimum of $f$ and one local maximum of $f$ per component.
Note: I don't know too much about this subject, so this answer may not be entirely correct.

Really cool, there is connection between characteristic and critical point. Thanks.
